# how to use map append correctly with lists of list in Racket

Tags: racket

i have this code :

```
(: min&max-lists : (Listof (Listof Any)) -> (Listof Any))
    
(define (min&max-lists lst)
  (apply append 
         (map (lambda (slst)
                (sublist-numbers slst)              ;; **
                (cons (sublist-numbers slst) '())   ;; *
              )
              lst)))
```

if I run this code with the line with two ** everything works fine, but when I run the code above with the line with one * it shows me like that :
***Type Checker: type mismatch
expected: (Listof Any)
given: Any in: slst***

how can I solve this? I see if i use the slst with another function it shows me that it is typed if Any and they need List of Any but if I use it like with two ** it works fine

Comment: what eaching language is this? what is in the `#lang` line?

Comment: Ah you just marked the lines with ** and * . I thought this is allowed in some dialect. This is not valid lisp code any more if you place stars around paranetheses. Never do that! use `;; **` and `;; *` instead - at the end of the line. - Use normal comments of the corresponding language always.

Comment: `(cons x '())` is equivalent to `(list x)`. Consider the difference between `(append '(1 2) '(3 4))` and `(append (list '(1 2)) (list '(3 4)))`.

Comment: Also, `(lambda (x) (f x))` is equivalent to `f`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `(cons (sublist-numbers slst) '())`:

```
(cons x '()) ;; => '(x)
;; which is nothing other than:
(list x)
```

If `x` is already a list - like in this case)
you have instead of `'(1 2 3)` one list layer around it: `'((1 2 3))`.
If you apply-append such results you get (Listof (Listof Any)) instead of just (Listof Any).

So, if you want to run using the line `*`, you have to change the typing to:

```
(: min&max-lists : (Listof (Listof Any)) -> (Listof (Listof Any)))
```